# How do I hide these folders

Tags: 12.04, directory

How do I hide a folder with a name like this:
Why Productive People Get Up Insanely Early   Fast Company   Business + Innovation_files

I download web pages complete and end up with two listings for each, the html file and the one above.  I've now got two listings for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case if you will add `.` in front of folder of your html file , your html file will not be able to access it.

There is a better way to hide the file without creating the path problem which is occurring due to  `.`  before folder.

- First create an empty file with name `.hidden` using `touch .hidden`
- Now open it using gedit.
- Add the file or folder name in it which you want to hide.
- Save it.

It will hide the file which are present in the `.hidden` file without changing its name.

Comment: Thank you but, that didn't work for me.  I put the ".hidden" file in the same directory as the file (directory) I want to hide (copy and paste, no mistakes) but it still shows whether gui file manager or cli "ls".